# Problem with the wx.querySelector().select.node() method

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I am trying to use this in a wechat miniprogram aplication and it is supposed to work, I am doing it just as the docs say, the problem is only with the node method because the others work fine

```
    wx.createSelectorQuery().select('.classname').node(function(res){
  console.log(res) 
}).exec()
```